# AMP Autocomplete: run some custom JS on SELECT event

Tags: javascript, amp-html

Is it possible to run some custom JS on the select event in AMP?

The select has auto-complete added to it. We want to save the ID of the selected item into a separate hidden field.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can do it with `amp-script`:
https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/

You can also change the state with `AMP.setState` and bind to the autocomplete amp events.

Check out `amp-bind`: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-bind/.
And `Actions and Events`: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events/

Comment: I was not able to run amp-script on the drop down event (select event). Are you sure that this is possible?